# React Native Mobile Apps Documentation Tools

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, documentation

I built a **`React Native`** project and trying to make a **`Documentation`** of it with some 3rd party tools. 
Is there any appplication that will help you to make **`Documentation`** of  **`React Native`** project?

I have a few in mind like :

- Espresso from Android Studio
- Appium (but I think this is for mobile automation. ***CMIIW***)

I need an app that help me to capture the screen of the `mobile apps`, list its process (*input, output, button click, etc)*, and export its result as a `.txt` or whatever format that easy to copy to `MS Word` for better formatting.